Click handler function prevents link to redirect (React js)
I have a click handler function that detects click on a <NavLink> tag and does the job of hiding some divs (mobile menu). But what it also does is prevents the Navlink to redirect to the page it is intended to. The behavior I want is both things to happen on click event:
1. Hide some divs (mobile menu div)
2. Redirect to the specified anchor link
What I'm getting is only first step. How can I achieve this?
This is my html:
<ul className="drop-content">
    <li><NavLink onClick={handleClick} to="/servicios/distribucion-de-peliculas">Distribución de películas</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink onClick={handleClick} to="/servicios/produccion-de-audiovisuales">Producción de audiovisuales</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink onClick={handleClick} to="/servicios/publicidad-en-cines">Publicidad en cines</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink onClick={handleClick} to="/servicios/laboratorio-digital">Laboratorio digital</NavLink></li>
</ul>

This is my click handler function:
const handleClick =() => {
        document.getElementById("nav").display(none);
        document.getElementById("side-menu").checked = false;
       }


What's the version of react-router-dom are you using?

Usually the react router is used to navigate. Depending on your version the implementation will change. If it's a newer version potentially with const navigate = useNavigate(); //+ navigate("/page"); in handleClick . A more detailed version on navigating with the router can be found in this answer
